# 404 response header using struts forward

Tags: http, struts, http-headers, wcs

Is it possible to set the http response header with a status of 404 instead of 200 when using struts forwards?

We have a generic error page that goes out with a status of 200OK. We want to update the header to show a 404 instead. Is that possible?

Comment: Is the generic error page a struts action or a static page?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use the `HttpServletResponse.setStatus(int)` method on your while you render the page (action or JSP).

Answer (score 0):

Given the `HttpServletResponse response` object passed to your handler, call `response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);`  See [sendError(int)](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendError%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) and [sendError(int,String)](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendError%28int%29)